# Google Places API only returns up to 5 results even with a 50,000 radius and keyword is food

Tags: php, json, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

Reading the documentation I saw it returns up to 20 results per query. Im puzzled why its only returning 5 results even though I have a 50,000 meter radius(Because I like to exaggerate when things arent working) and my keyword is food. I mean there has to be tons of food in a 50,000 meter radius

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=50000&keyword=food&key=myKey
```

[image]

Comment: What is the location?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that as Xingzhou Liu mentioned, food is deprecated

> The following types are deprecated, and will continue to be supported
>   until February 16, 2017: establishment, finance, food,
>   general_contractor, grocery_or_supermarket, health, place_of_worship.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/supported_types

However, the query provided returns only 9 based on the search criteria.  The Lat. and Lon. might not be 100% land or populated.

The query below using a different Lat. and Lon. returns the correct number of results
[image: Results]

Read the following

> Accessing Additional Results
>
> By default, each Nearby Search or Text Search returns up to 20
>   establishment results per query; however, each search can return as
>   many as 60 results, split across three pages. If your search will
>   return more than 20, then the search response will include an
>   additional value — next_page_token. Pass the value of the
>   next_page_token to the pagetoken parameter of a new search to see the
>   next set of results. If the next_page_token is null, or is not
>   returned, then there are no further results. There is a short delay
>   between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become
>   valid. Requesting the next page before it is available will return an
>   INVALID_REQUEST response. Retrying the request with the same
>   next_page_token will return the next page of results.
>
> For example, in the query below, we search for restaurants near
>   Darling Harbour, in Sydney Australia, and rank the results by
>   distance. You can see that the response contains a next_page_token
>   property.

**For more than 20**

**Request 1:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&rankby=distance&types=food&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

**Response 1:**

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "next_page_token" : "CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-HQIx1hr5BrT4zBaEko29ANsXtp9mrqN0yrKWhf-y2PUpHRLQb1GT-mtxNcXou8TwkXhi1Jbk-ReY7oulyuvKSQrw1lgJElggGlo0d6indiH1U-tDwquw4tU_UXoQ_sj8OBo8XBUuWjuuFShqmLMP-0W59Vr6CaXdLrF8M3wFR4dUUhSf5UC4QCLaOMVP92lyh0OdtF_m_9Dt7lz-Wniod9zDrHeDsz_by570K3jL1VuDKTl_U1cJ0mzz_zDHGfOUf7VU1kVIs1WnM9SGvnm8YZURLTtMLMWx8-doGUE56Af_VfKjGDYW361OOIj9GmkyCFtaoCmTMIr5kgyeUSnB-IEhDlzujVrV6O9Mt7N4DagR6RGhT3g1viYLS4kO5YindU6dm3GIof1Q",
   "results" : [
      {
       ....
```

**Request 2:**

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?pagetoken=CpQCAgEAAFxg8o-eU7_uKn7Yqjana-HQIx1hr5BrT4zBaEko29ANsXtp9mrqN0yrKWhf-y2PUpHRLQb1GT-mtxNcXou8TwkXhi1Jbk-ReY7oulyuvKSQrw1lgJElggGlo0d6indiH1U-tDwquw4tU_UXoQ_sj8OBo8XBUuWjuuFShqmLMP-0W59Vr6CaXdLrF8M3wFR4dUUhSf5UC4QCLaOMVP92lyh0OdtF_m_9Dt7lz-Wniod9zDrHeDsz_by570K3jL1VuDKTl_U1cJ0mzz_zDHGfOUf7VU1kVIs1WnM9SGvnm8YZURLTtMLMWx8-doGUE56Af_VfKjGDYW361OOIj9GmkyCFtaoCmTMIr5kgyeUSnB-IEhDlzujVrV6O9Mt7N4DagR6RGhT3g1viYLS4kO5YindU6dm3GIof1Q&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchPaging